# I need help using recursion to navigate every element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom

I need to use recursion to navigate every element in the DOM, and for every body element, determine if it is an element node. If it is, I need to add a child node to it. I need to use JavaScript for this assignment. Here is what I have so far in my JavaScript file:

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {

      var highlightButton = document.getElementById("highlight");
      highlightButton.addEventListener('click', search);

      function search(node) {
       if (node.nodeType === 1) {
       var spanEl = document.createElement("span");
       spanEl.className = "hoverNode";
       node.appendChild(spanEl);
       spanEl.innerHTML = spanEl.parentNode.tagName;
     }
   }
 })
```

I understand how to append a child node, but I don't know how to traverse the entire DOM and append the child node to every element.

Comment: A document can have only one HTML element, and [*body* elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) can only be children of the HTML element. Body elements are, by definition, element nodes. So you don't need recursion to do this. If you just want to go over every element in a document, that's a different story. Unless "*every body element*" actually means "every element in the body"?

Comment: This is a school assignment that requires the use of recursion. It specifically asks us to navigate every element in the DOM, and for each element within the body, determine whether it is an element node (nodeType == 1) element and then add a child node to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given "every body element" actually means "every element in the body", you can start with an element and get all its child elements. Loop over the child elements and if any is type 1 and has a child nodes, you call the function again with the element.

If it doesn't have children, go to the next child, etc. The following is just an example of recursing over all the nodes and picking out just the type 1s. You can modify it to do whatever.

```js
// Call with a document or HTML element
function checkBodyElements(node) {

  // Recursive function
  function traverseBody(node) {

    if (node.childNodes.length) {

      // Loop over every child node
      node.childNodes.forEach(child => {

        // If it's a type 1, call the function recursively
        if (child.nodeType == 1) {
          console.log(child.tagName, child.nodeType)
          traverseBody(child);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Get the body element      
  let body = node.querySelector('body');
  
  // If a body element was found, traverse its children
  if (body) {
    traverseBody(body);
  }
}

window.onload = checkBodyElements(document);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <p><span></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><span></span>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any specific reason that implies the creation of a recursive function**, other than to support older browsers, like IE6 and 7?

**If no**, you could simply use `document.body.querySelectorAll('*')` to select every element node in the DOM while ignoring the ones outside the body element. An example would be:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var highlightButton = document.getElementById("highlight");

    function search () {
        document.body.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function (el) { 
            var spanEl = document.createElement('span');

            spanEl.innerHTML = el.tagName; 
            spanEl.className = 'hoverNode';
            el.appendChild(spanEl); 
        });
    }

    highlightButton.addEventListener('click', search);
});
```

**If yes**, then an option would be:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var highlightButton = document.getElementById("highlight");

    // traverse downwards from rootEl while excluding Comment elements on IE6 7 & 8
    function traverseDOMFrom (rootEl, iterator) {
        if (!rootEl || rootEl.nodeType !== 1 || typeof iterator !== 'function') {
            return;
        }

        if (rootEl.children && rootEl.children.length > 0) {
            Array.prototype.slice.call(rootEl.children).forEach(function (el) {
                traverseDOMFrom(el, iterator);
            });
        }

        iterator(rootEl);
    }

    function search () {
        traverseDOMFrom(document.body, function (el) { 
            var spanEl = document.createElement('span');

            spanEl.innerHTML = el.tagName;
            spanEl.className = 'hoverNode';
            el.appendChild(spanEl); 
        });
    }

    highlightButton.addEventListener('click', search);
});
```

**Notice that in both cases, a polyfill for [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://gist.github.com/hufyhang/c303ce1b80c7b6f8a73e) and for [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://gist.github.com/eirikbacker/2864711) would be necessary if you want to support those features on IE6, 7 and 8!** Otherwise you could also achieve the same results by iterating the element's array with a custom [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead, as for this `.addEventListener`, a simple [.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event handler could be used if there's no need to support multiple listeners.